# Simple RNN Error "Input and hidden tensors are not at the same device, found input tensor at cuda:0 and hidden tensor at cpu" How to?

Tags: pytorch

I'm working on a basic RNN-NLP classifier using PyTorch, and trying to use CUDA for acceleration.(On Google_Colab)
but, I can't solve this error.
The code is written like this.

## error message

Input and hidden tensors are not at the same device, found input tensor at cuda:0 and hidden tensor at cpu

## RNN class

```
class RNN(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, emb_size, hidden_size, output_size):
    super().__init__()
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.emb = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, emb_size)
    self.rnn = nn.RNN(emb_size, hidden_size, nonlinearity='tanh', batch_first=True)
    self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

  def forward(self, x):
    self.batch_size = x.size()[0]
    hidden = self.init_hidden()
    emb = self.emb(x)
    out, hidden = self.rnn(emb, hidden)
    out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :])
    return out

  def init_hidden(self):
    hidden = torch.zeros(1, self.batch_size, self.hidden_size)
    return hidden
```

## device

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
```

## Setting var

```
VOCAB_SIZE = len(word_id.keys()) +1
EMB_SIZE = 300
OUTPUT_SIZE = 4
HIDDEN_SIZE = 50

model = RNN(VOCAB_SIZE,EMB_SIZE, HIDDEN_SIZE, OUTPUT_SIZE)

model = model.to(device)
```

## Predict

```
for i in range(10):
  # datasetet　の、リスト０indexに入力要素
  X, y = dataset_train[i]
  X = X.to(device)
  print(torch.softmax(model(X.unsqueeze(0)), dim=1))
```

This code works on CPU. but, can't works on "GPU".
Follow this error, I try to make some fix code.
ex) hidden.to(device),,,,

but,I can't solve...
Pleas someone tell me how to solve.
Thank you very much for my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't doing something like the following work?

```py
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "CPU")

class RNN(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, emb_size, hidden_size, output_size):
    super().__init__()
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.emb = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, emb_size)
    self.rnn = nn.RNN(emb_size, hidden_size, nonlinearity='tanh', batch_first=True)
    self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
    self.to(device)

  def forward(self, x):
    self.batch_size = x.size()[0]
    hidden = self.init_hidden()
    emb = self.emb(x)
    out, hidden = self.rnn(emb, hidden)
    out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :])
    return out

  def init_hidden(self):
    hidden = torch.zeros(1, self.batch_size, self.hidden_size).to(device)
    return hidden
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Akhil !!
but, I try classification with this code, Runtime error [RuntimeError: cuDNN error: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM] appear...

my try code below
"""
VOCAB_SIZE = len(word_id.keys()) +1
EMB_SIZE = 300
OUTPUT_SIZE = 4
HIDDEN_SIZE = 50

model = RNN(VOCAB_SIZE,EMB_SIZE, HIDDEN_SIZE, OUTPUT_SIZE)
model = model.to(device)

for i in range(10):
  # datasetet　の、リスト０indexに入力要素
  X, y = dataset_train[i]
  X = X.to(device)
  #y = y.to(device)
  print(torch.softmax(model(X.unsqueeze(0)), dim=1))

"""

Comment: Can you share your colab file or the notebook you're working on?

Comment: Thanks for your great help.
code is here.(but,masked path names and more)
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1i05asUmHso6fDZXigPN-jszfqpbUaz_Q?usp=sharing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).